# Need help to convert a Matlab script into a Mathematica script?

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics, linear-algebra, matlab

I would like to convert a small script but a little technical in Mathematica language. Here is the Matlab script :

```
clear;
clc;
format long;

% 2 Fisher Matrixes symbolic : FISH_GCsp_SYM, : 1 cosmo params + 1 bias spectro put for common
%                              FISH_XC_SYM : 1 cosmo params + 2 bias photo correlated

% GCsp Fisher : 1 param cosmo and 1 bias spectro which will be summed
FISH_GCsp_SYM = sym('sp1_', [2,2], 'real');
% Force symmetry for GCsp
FISH_GCsp_SYM = tril(FISH_GCsp_SYM.') + triu(FISH_GCsp_SYM,1)

% GCph Fisher : 1 param cosmo and 2 bias photo correlated
FISH_XC_SYM = sym('xc1_', [3,3], 'real');
% Force symmetry for GCph
FISH_XC_SYM = tril(FISH_XC_SYM.') + triu(FISH_XC_SYM,1)

% Brutal Common Bias : sum of cosmo param ans bias : FISH_ALL1 = first left matrix
FISH_ALL1 = sym('xc1_', [2,2], 'real');

%{
FISH_ALL1(1,1) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1,1) + FISH_XC_SYM(1,1);
FISH_ALL1(2,2) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(2,2) + FISH_XC_SYM(2,2);
%}

FISH_ALL1(1:2,1:2) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1:2,1:2) + FISH_XC_SYM(1:2,1:2);

FISH_ALL1 = (tril(FISH_ALL1.') + triu(FISH_ALL1,1));

% Adding new observable "O" terms
FISH_O_SYM = sym('o_', [2,2], 'real');
% Defining symbolic bias for "O" terms
FISH_BIAS_SYM = sym('b_', [2], 'real');
% Definition of F_ij = Matrix for adding elements
FISH_O_SYM(1,1) = 4*FISH_BIAS_SYM(1)^2/FISH_BIAS_SYM(2)^4
FISH_O_SYM(2,2) = 4*FISH_BIAS_SYM(1)^4/FISH_BIAS_SYM(2)^6
FISH_O_SYM(1,2) = -4*FISH_BIAS_SYM(1)^3/FISH_BIAS_SYM(2)^5
% Definition of sigma_o
SIGMA_O = sym('sigma_o', 'real');
%SIGMA_O = 1
FISH_O_SYM = 1/(SIGMA_O*SIGMA_O) * FISH_O_SYM
% Force symmetry
%FISH_O_SYM = (tril(FISH_O_SYM.') + triu(FISH_O_SYM,1))
FISH_O_SYM


% Multiply by a numerical unknown sigma_o
%syms sigma_o
%sigma_o = 1e-3
%FISH_O_SYM = 1./sigma_o^2*FISH_O_SYM

% Second on right Fisher matrix : Big Fisher on right
FISH_SYM = sym('xc1_', [4,4], 'real');

% Param cosmo
FISH_SYM(1,1) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1,1) + FISH_XC_SYM(1,1);
% Add O observable
FISH_SYM(2,2) = FISH_SYM(2,2) + FISH_O_SYM(1,1);
FISH_SYM(3,3) = FISH_SYM(3,3) + FISH_O_SYM(2,2);
FISH_SYM(2,3) = FISH_SYM(2,3) + FISH_O_SYM(1,2);
FISH_SYM(3,2) = FISH_SYM(3,2) + FISH_O_SYM(2,1);
% Introduce spectro off-diagonal for column/raw 2
FISH_SYM(1,2) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1,2) + FISH_XC_SYM(1,2);
FISH_SYM(2,1) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(2,1) + FISH_XC_SYM(2,1);
% Force symmetry
FISH_SYM = (tril(FISH_SYM.') + triu(FISH_SYM,1));

FISH_SYM

% Marginalize FISH_SYM2 in order to get back a 2x2 matrix

% Invert to marginalyze
COV_ALL = inv(FISH_SYM);
% Marginalize
COV_ALL([3,4],:) = [];
COV_ALL(:,[3,4]) = [];
FISH_ALL2 = inv(COV_ALL);

FISH_ALL1;
FISH_ALL2;

% Matricial equation to solve
eqn = FISH_ALL1 == FISH_ALL2;

% Solving : matrix1 equal to matrix2
%sol = solve(eqn, [FISH_O_SYM(1,1),FISH_O_SYM(2,2),FISH_O_SYM(1,2)])
%sol = solve(eqn, [FISH_O_SYM(1,1),FISH_O_SYM(2,2),FISH_O_SYM(1,2),SIGMA_O])
[solx, parameters, conditions] = solve(eqn, SIGMA_O, 'ReturnConditions', true);
assume(conditions)
restriction = [solx > 1e-6, solx < 1e-2 ];
solk = solve(restriction,parameters)
valx = subs(solx,parameters,solk)
```

I have only one unknown (SIGMA_O) which appears multiple times in the system of equations

The system seems to be solved but I don't know how to get a numerical value of this unknown or maybe a simple symbolic expression of it.
If someone could help me to convert it, I would be grateful.

Comment: It might be much easier to explain what you are trying to accomplish and what you gave tried so far.

Comment: @MarcoB . the context is about Fisher formalism. As I said, at the end of my first analysis, I get 2 matrixes which have to be equal. I introduce in the second the unkonws o_1_1, o_1_2 and o_2_2 : So finally, I have a system of 4 equations with 3 unknows to solve.

Comment: Why not write your problem in Mathematica? Let us know where you get stuck and I'm sure someone will help.

Comment: I need help about this solving and I thought that showing me the equivalent of my Matlab script in Mathematica would be a very good example for me to understand and grasp the subtilities of this new language.

Comment: Sorry, the initial Matlab script had a mistake, I think now the system of equations is right.

Comment: I agree with the close-vote reason, but in the OP's defense, they have offered a bounty for the work. It may be mere rep points, but someone might want the points or to help out. I think as long as the bounty remains open, we might allow a courtesy to the OP and anyone who wants to work on it, and leave the question open. Then if no one has answered, it could be closed.

Comment: I know little about MATLAB, but are you sure the line `FISH_ALL1(1:2,1:2) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1:2,1:2) + FISH_XC_SYM(1:2:3);` is correct?

Comment: why not try http://matlink.org/ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question seems to miss some points in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This answer is for helping you to write the code by yourself and if you encounter any problem, feel free to post another question.

In Mathematica use:

- `(* comment *)` syntax for commenting your code
- `LowerTriangularize` function for accessing the lower triangular part of a matrix
- `UpperTriangularize` function for accessing the upper triangular part of a matrix
- `Transpose` function to transpose a matrix (`.'` equivalent)
- `Inverse` function to invert a square matrix
- `"` (double quote) for strings
- `fn[]` syntax to call function `fn`
- `matrix[[ ]]` to access part of `matrix`
- `matrix[[start;;end;;step]]` gives parts `start` through `end` in steps of `step`

> `LowerTriangularize` and `UpperTriangularize` accept a second argument just like Matlab

As far as I know, Mathematica doesn't have a function like Matlab's `sym`, for mimicking that behavior, run this code to have a similar function with the same name:

```
sym[prefix_String, size_List] := 
 Array[Symbol[prefix <> StringRiffle[List@##, "v"]] &, size]
```

#### Comparison:

In Mathematica (the code above should execute first):

```
sym["sp1", {4, 4}]

(*Out: {{sp11v1, sp11v2}, {sp12v1, sp12v2}} *)
```

Matlab:

```matlab
sym('sp1_', [2,2], 'real')

% Out:
%     [sp1_1_1, sp1_1_2]
%     [sp1_2_1, sp1_2_2]
```

Note:
`_` in Mathematica has a special use case and can't be used in variable/function names as a separator, so when you copy your code inside Mathematica, remove all the `_` first (the `sym` defined earlier, uses `v` as the separator).

To give you a better picture, I will convert these Matlab codes to Mathematica:

#### Matlab

```matlab
% 0
clear;

% 1
var1 = sym('sp1_', [4,4], 'real');

% 2
var1(1,1) = 1;

% 3
var1(2:3,2:3) = 0

% 4
var1([3,4],:) = [];

% 5
var2 = tril(var1.',-1);
```

#### Mathematica:

```
(* 0 *)
Clear["Global`*"];

(* define sym function *)
sym[prefix_String, size_List] := 
 Array[Symbol[prefix <> StringRiffle[List@##, "v"]] &, size]

(* 1 *)
var1 = sym["sp1", {4, 4}];

(* 2 *)
var1[[1, 1]] = 1;

(* 3 *)
var1[[2 ;; 3, 2 ;; 3]] = 0;

(* 4 *)
var1 = Delete[var1, {{3}, {4}}];

(* 5 *)
var2 = LowerTriangularize[Transpose[var1], -1];
```

I would also encourage you to read the documentation, especially [Vectors and Matrices Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Lists.html#2534) and [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).